# get IPA file in Visual Studio 2017 Cross platform app (Xamarin)

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

Where is Ad hoc in Visual Studio 2017 Cross platform app (xamarin)?
How can i export IPA file in Visual studio Cross platform app (xamarin)?

Comment: Go into the project properties and check the box for generating an IPA, also see: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/app_distribution/ipa_support/

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your ios project in your solution pad and go to options.
Navigate to "iOS IPA Options".

Make sure "Build iTunes Package Archive (IPA) is checked.

Your IPA will be available after you run the app in your bin folder.

Comment: should i run in iPhone or iPhone simulator? and i run in debug mode or release mode?

Comment: Run as iPhone and in Release mode. Make sure you got your provisioning profiles set right for this mode.

Comment: I can't run but i deploy ios project and application install successfully on iPhone and ipa file create in bin folder. i removed application and install application with iTunes on mac. but shows 'unable to install' error.

Comment: What kind of provision profile do you use? I don't think you can install IPA's signed with an Developer Provisioning Profile from iTunes.